# How to install bison on mac OSX

Tags: macos, bison, thrift

I'm trying to install Thrift on my macbook.
Otherwise I got an error:

> configure: error: Bison version 2.5 or higher must be installed on the system!

So tried to install Bison on my OS, but I didn't find tutorial on internet.
Does anyone who can tell me how to install Bison on my system ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 94, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844621/1048539). You can install with brew:

```bash
brew install bison
```

Then update your scripts or your shell config to use brew's bison first in
your PATH:

```bash
export PATH="$(brew --prefix bison)/bin:$PATH"
```

Or

```bash
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: When would it be necessary to unlink bison?  I am sure to forget.

Comment: Why do we need to link and unlink? When should we unlink it again after linking?

Comment: Brew no longer allows force linking system provided packages. Use `export PATH="$(brew --prefix bison)/bin:$PATH"` when brew's bison is needed in your scripts.

Comment: I updated this answer to reflect that my previous comment.

Comment: sometimes you might need bsion2.7, so `brew install bison@2.7` then `export PATH="$(brew --prefix bison@2.7)/bin:$PATH"` to your config

Answer (score 14):

I needed to set `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"`
`brew install bison` installs the bison new version at /usr/local/Cellar but this path is not set in the $PATH

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.
I have the same issue on macOS 10.15.2

Answer (score 13):

To save a ton of time use either [Macports](http://macports.org) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  These will install all dependent packages for you.

I use Macports, and after installing it, it's as simple as:

```
$ sudo port install thrift
```

and it will be done before your coffee is ready.

Comment: I wrote

"sudo port install thrift"
on my terminal, but there was an error

"Error: Port thrift not found
Can we find a solution ?"

Kind Regards.

Comment: @bonzaitek Strange as that port is [available](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/thrift/Portfile).  Did you follow all the Macports installation steps (i.e. `sudo port selfupdate`)?

Comment: Oops... No I didn't, the only handling I did is install from source like
"
$ curl -O https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
$ tar xf MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
$ cd MacPorts-2.3.3/
"
In your opinion, this link tutorial is it correct for the rest of the installation ?
https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.shell.html

Kind Regards

Comment: You only need to install like that if you're running El Capitan as it's not officially supported.  If you are running non-beta OSX, then there is binary installer available.

Comment: @NeeleshSalian Yeah I mentioned Homebrew in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I got a warning after `brew install bison` and when trying `brew link bison --force`

```
bison is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because some formulae require a newer version of bison.

If you need to have bison first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find bison you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/bison/lib"
```

So I suggest you to add these two above flags, instead of forcing the link of `/usr/local`.

So, above all, you will need below three steps:

```
brew install bison
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/bison/lib"
```

Comment: Don't forget to do "source ~/.bash_profile" for this to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

rename the default bison under dir:
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin$'

install the newest version of bison by homebrew:

```
brew install bison
```

link the bison :

```
brew link bison --force
```

if you need unlink the bison and rename the bison from xcode.
best wish ~~

Comment: Brew no longer allows force linking system provided packages. Default `bison` shouldn't be renamed. Use `export PATH="$(brew --prefix bison)/bin:$PATH"` when brew's bison is needed in your scripts.